# What kind of glasses is Ronnie Kray wearing?

Tags: props, historical-accuracy, legend

In the [trailer [Youtube.com]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02oNGZgW6po) for the upcoming ganster movie [Legend](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3569230/), we see Ronnie Kray (cast by Tom Hardy) wearing the following glasses:

[image: Sample image]

Are these glasses accurate for the timespan (1950 - 1960)?
Are such glasses still made today, leaving aside the Rayban Clubmasters, that are similar, but quite different in detail?

Comment: Malcolm X wore [half-rim glasses](http://www.zennioptical.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Malcolm-X-Half-Rim-Glasses.jpg) in the 1950s;

Comment: (chuckles) Tom Hardy playing a gangster? Say it ain't so. (squee!) Tom Hardy playing _TWO_ gangsters? I am such a fanboy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The glasses are generally referred to as "[Half-rim glasses](http://www.eyewearbrands.com/designer%20glasses/frame%20style/half%20rim/)", "[Brow-line glasses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browline_glasses)" (or more colloquially "[Eyebrow glasses](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Shipping-quality-TR-90-half-rim-men-eyebrow-brand-optical-glasses-eyeglasses-frame-spectacle-frame/341111402.html)"). They were indeed appropriate to the period. You can see Ronnie Kray wearing them in the photo below from the early 1960s.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it's sometimes hard to search for something when you don't know the terminology, so this helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The glasses Tom Hardy wears in the film are French Amor Browline Glasses. I have a pair of these myself and they are exactly the same as the ones in the film 'Legend'.

[image]

Comment: @Dugs why you adding duplicate answer? Better to improve existing one.

Comment: Bounty for finding the exact glasses.